# Assigning different names to textboxes in a loop in php

Tags: php

I had generated few textboxes in a loop n named them differntly.. but the retrieving of data from those boxes is not working.. Please help me..

code for creating those textboxes

```
$i=0;  
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql ))
   { 
       echo "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td><td>".$data['name'] . " </td><td>
       <input type='text' name='obtmarks".$i."'></td></tr>";  $i++; 
   }
```

I have to retrieve that data n place it another table

code for retrieving the data

```
$i=0;


while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql1 )) 
 { 

    $as=mysql_query("INSERT INTO marks values('".$data['idno']."','".$data['name']."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['obtmarks".$i."'])."')");
 $i++;  }
```

Please help me.. thank u in advance..

Comment: clentfort is right, you should look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php

Answer (score 3):

In your `mysql_real_escape_string` you have `$_POST['obtmarks".$i."']`, it should be `$_POST['obtmarks'.$i]`. Also you should stop using the deprecated `mysql_` methods. They are deprecated and will be removed in the future

Comment: You should accept this answer then as the right one. [Here is explained how it works and what it is good for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) You specially should accept answers to motivate other people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['obtmarks'.$i."']` u put a `"` instead of a `'`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using array notation in your name attributes (AS in name="foo[]" or name="foo[0]" or even name="foo[bar]" etc) for arrays of form data, then you can simply iterate the array $_POST['foo']